# Execute javascript trough Internet Explorer's com interface using PowerShell

Tags: internet-explorer, com, powershell, webautomation

I am writing some Internet Explorer automation scripts using PowerShell. Here is how I start the IE com object:

```
$ie = New-Object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Navigate("about:blank")
$ie.visible = $true

$doc = $ie.Document
```

So, what I would like to do is to execute some javascript on the `$doc` object. For example, I have an item on the page that has an `onclick` event which executes `submitCommand('lookup')`, so I'd like to run that directly on the `$doc` instead of having to find the object on the page and then calling the `Click()` method on it.

It would be easier as the object has no name nor id, making it very sensible to change as I can only rely on it's position on the page (eg: the 11th span item on the page).

Alternatively, how would you select elements based on their class? That would help a lot as the "button" has it's own class.

Thanks

Comment: Alternatively, how would you select elements based on their class? That would help a lot as the "button" has it's own class.

Comment: @Philippe: Instead of commenting your own question with more info and questions why not simply edit the existing question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$spans=@($ie.document.getElementsByTagName("SPAN"))`

Pipe to where-object to filter the one you need (based on its attributes) and then call the click method, for example:

```
$span11 = $spans | where {$_.innerText -eq 'something'}
$span11.click()
```

Comment: Not exactly the solution I was hoping for, but definitely a cleaner solution to my issue. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, is there any way to store the result of the where in an array? In case there are more than one result to the filtering, only the first one is returned if you store it in a variable like this?

Comment: You can wrap it in '@()':

$span11 = @($spans | where {$_.innerText -eq 'something'})