# how to call a jquery from powershell

Tags: jquery, powershell, teamcity

I configured a svn file in Teamcity server (CI). Now I got the build log after each check in happened for the svn file. I need to access the build result and move that result into another web space. I have a jquery to upload a content to that web space. So I wish to use this jquery in Teamcity server's build step through Powershell script. Is this possible ?

Comment: [It seems you could](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444330/execute-javascript-trough-internet-explorers-com-interface-using-powershell)

Comment: A function from [poshcode](http://poshcode.org/2351).