# Run javascript document from PowerShell script

Tags: javascript, jquery, powershell

We want to create PowerShell script that will call javascript document, stored on our server. PowerShell script would be started on Task Scheduler at some time we define.
Javascript document is about checking some values in table we have on page.

I presume this is possible, but I ask, just to be sure as we found none examples.
If anyone can share example or suggestion where to check it.

I don't ask for solution or "How to do it", just suggestion if this is possible and link to examples would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If your talking about Node.js not JavaScript then you can use the node command to run a node.js program. First you must download Node.JS if you don't have it already (https://nodejs.org). This is the syntax for the node command:

```
node path/to/javascript/file
```

As long as the program doesn't use any web browser feature such as `alert()` your program will work.

Answer (score -3):

A quick google can always point you in the right direction. These are the first two results I found.

https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/powershell-abcs-j-is-for-javascript

[Execute javascript trough Internet Explorer's com interface using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444330/execute-javascript-trough-internet-explorers-com-interface-using-powershell)

Without more information people on this site wont be able to help you much